# restting jquery progress bar

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, reset, blueimp

I have a simple jquery progress bar representing file upload and I was hoping for some help to reset it after each upload.

I have tried the following which in my mind should work...however not,

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'Home/UploadFiles',
    autoUpload: true,
    done: function (e, data) {
        $('.file_name').html(data.result.name);
        $('.file_type').html(data.result.type);
        $('.file_size').html(data.result.size);
        alert("File was uploaded");
        $('.file_name').html("");
        $('.file_type').html("");
        $('.file_size').html("");
        //this is where I am attempting to reset the bar after 1.5 secs
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css('width', 0);
        }, 1500);

    }
}).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong to change the `position` of the progress bar you need to change the `value`:

```
$( ".progress" ).progressbar({ value: 25 });
```

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#option-value

Comment: thanks. I also noticed a syntax error which I rectified and now it seems fine. $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', 0);